# Как импортировать переменную из функции в другой файл Python

Tags: python

Делаю Телеграм бота с парсером. В файле с парсером есть функция, в которой находится переменная. Как вынести её из функции я не знаю, ибо она нужна внутри (такая структура программы). Мне необходимо эту переменную импортировать в функцию в другом файле. Вот небольшая часть кода для понимания:
Та самая переменная:

```
items = {
    dict_key: {
        'full_item_name': [],
        'paintseed': [],
        'floatvalue': [],
        'price': [],
        'item_url': [],
        'stickers_dict': []
    }
}
```

Импортирую в другой файл вот так:

```
from items.parser import *
```

Использовать переменную нужно тут:

```
for url in items_urls:
    parse(url)
    for full_item_name, paintseed, floatvalue, price, item_url, stickers_dict in itertools.zip_longest(items['full_item_name'], items['paintseed'], items['floatvalue'], items['price'], items['item_url'], items['stickers_dict']):
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
KeyError: 'full_item_name'
```

Что только не пробовал. Думаю что решение не сложное. Спасибо всем за помощь

P.S.
Вот пример немного заполненного словаря:

```
items = {
    0: {
        'full_item_name': ['full_item_name0'],
        'paintseed': ['paintseed0'],
        'floatvalue': ['floatvalue0'],
        'price': ['price0'],
        'item_url': ['item_url0'],
        'stickers_dict': ['stickers_dict0']
    },
    1: {
        'full_item_name': ['full_item_name1'],
        'paintseed': ['paintseed1'],
        'floatvalue': ['floatvalue1'],
        'price': ['price1'],
        'item_url': ['item_url1'],
        'stickers_dict': ['stickers_dict1']
    },
    2: {
        'full_item_name': ['full_item_name2'],
        'paintseed': ['paintseed2'],
        'floatvalue': ['floatvalue2'],
        'price': ['price2'],
        'item_url': ['item_url2'],
        'stickers_dict': ['stickers_dict2']
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: А вам не легче обьявить эту переменную в начале кода а потом изменить её уже в функции но перед этим поставить `global название переменной`?

Comment: @Іван Шнір проблема в том, что эта переменная являет собой динамический словарь и напрямую зависит от переменной dict_key, которую в функции необходимо увеличить после каждой удачной итерации. Если вынести и items, и dict_key, то получаю такую ошибку UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_key' referenced before assignment

Comment: Содержимое `items` меняется в процессе цикла по `itertools.zip_longest(items... и т.д.`?

Comment: @Roman Konoval нет, этот цикл проходится по элементам и формирует из них сообщения, которое отправляет бот. Но я планировал сделать что бы когда этот цикл закончится, удалять все значения словаря, при этом оставляя его поля. Но пока не придумал как это реализовать

Comment: т.е. в items на верхнем уровне всегда один элемент, но имя ключа заранее не известно?

Comment: @Roman Konoval не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду. Но если про dict_key, то он просто увеличивается на единицу, а остальные ключи по типу full_item_name хоть и являются списком, но хранят в себе одно значение (сделано для удобства). И эти значения могут быть любыми, так как это результат парсинга

Comment: `items` это словарь, т.е. объект типа `dict`. Словарь хранит для ключа какое-то значение. Вопрос в том, может ли в словаре `items` храниться больше одного элемента (т.е. больше одного ключа)? `items = {dict_key: {...}}` всегда создает новый словарь с одним элементом (ключ будет иметь значение из переменной `dict_key`, а собственно значение задается в присваивании). Добавляются ли когда-нибудь в этот словарь (именно в него на верхнем уровне, а не в какой-то список внутри) новые элементы?

Comment: @Roman Konoval добавил пример заполненного словаря. Надеюсь правильно вас понял. Спасибо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120074/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-iiiyth1k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле с itertools.zip_longest оказалась ошибка, так как не указал [dict_key]. Саму переменную импортировал так

```
from items.parser import *
```

И инициализировал так:

```
items = parse(url)
```

При этом функция parse() возвращает этот список items

```
return items
```